# RabbitMqBundle, always getting error. Symfony2

Tags: symfony, configuration, rabbitmq

i've just installed the RabbitMqBundle for Symfony2.

https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle

I've followed the example on the page, literally copy&pasted the configuration and i'm always getting this error:

```
Warning: DOMElement::setAttribute() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
```

A bit further down the line:

```
at DOMElement->setAttribute('class', object(Definition)) in XmlDumper.php line 182
```

Does anyone have an idea? Did i do anything wrong? Just installed via composer etc.

Regards

Comment: Show your configuration.

Comment: It's literally copy&pasted from the git-page. Go to the "usage" part and you'll see the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Actually updating from Symfony 2.6.3 to 2.6.8 fixed it!

Sorry.

Regards